# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list (in python 3)

Tags: python

I am trying to label my dataset containing jpg images of devanagari characters. But I am getting the type error.Does anybody have a fix on this. The code is as below :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

direc=glob.glob('./consonants/*') 
# This line I am using to get the specific 
# folder containing devanagari character images.

label=[]
img_list=[]

for i,consonants in enumerate (direc):
    img_list=glob.glob(direc)
    for img in img_list:
        input_img=plt.imread(direc + '/'+ consonants + '/'+ img )
        label.append(i)
```

Comment: `direct` is a list. Did you want to use `consonants` in the `plt.imread` line?

Comment: `label.append(i)` where does `i` come from?

Comment: yeah i am using this line to read the images inside the consonants folder. Consonant folder contains 36 different folders containing 36 different consonants.

Comment: label.append(i) where does i come from?                                                    for i,consonants in enumerate (direc) 6th line @Alexander Reynolds

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob()` already gives you the full path:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

label = []

for i, path in enumerate(glob.glob('./consonants/*')):
    for img in glob.glob(path):
        input_img = plt.imread(img)
    label.append(i)
```

Comment: I got the following error after executing this prog. @Adirio                    File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2477, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './consonants\\1'

Comment: Thats a permission problem, you are executing the python script with a user that can not access those files. That has nothing to do with the file searching algorithm